# position_dodgev causes error in order of connecting points in geom_line

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot over a timecourse x with y values that are often repeated (integer scores 1-4) and I want to visualize many subjects at once.

Because there is so much overlap, a vertical position dodge would be ideal, such as `position_dodgev` from [ggstance](/questions/tagged/ggstance) package. However, when I try to connect the dots with geom_line, the order of the connection gets messed up and is connected based on y values and not x values.

I tried a coordinate flip work-around which was not successful. And replacing `geom_line` with `geom_path` (making sure it was ordered on the x scale) also did not work.

Here is a reproducible example:

```
#data
df<-tibble(x=c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5),
           y=c(1,2,3,7,7,1,2,3,7,7,2,1,6,7,7),
           group=c('a','a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b','b','c','c','c','c','c'))


#horizontal dodge masks groups
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y,col=group,group=group)) +
  geom_point(position=position_dodge(width=0.3))+
  geom_line(position=position_dodge(width=0.3))


#line connection error with vertical dodge
library(ggstance)
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y,col=group,group=group)) +
  geom_point(position=position_dodgev(height=0.3))+
  geom_line(position=position_dodgev(height=0.3))
```

Horizontal dodge works as expected but does not allow visualization of all the overlapped groups in a stretch of repeated y values. Vertical dodge from `ggstance` connected the dots in group c in the wrong order.

[image]

Comment: A possible solution: `ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y,col=group,group=group)) +
  geom_point(position=position_jitter(w=0.1, h=0.1, seed=123))+
  geom_line(position=position_jitter(w=0.1, h=0.1, seed=123))`

Comment: @MarcoSandri I am not comfortable using `position_jitter` with `geom_line` since it does not preserve slope of the line. Personal opinion tho. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what exactly causes the issue. Knowing that `position_dodge` is not intended to be used with `geoms` and [it's been called a bug](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/1119), I am surprised and not at the same time about this issue.

But in any case, I found a workaround by disassembling the plot using `ggplot_build`, rearranging the points for `geom_line` within that object and then reassembling the plot again; look below:

```
g <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y,col=group,group=group)) +
  geom_point(position=position_dodgev(height=0.3)) +
  geom_line(position=position_dodgev(height=0.3))

gg <- ggplot_build(g)

# -- look at gg$data to understand following lines --
#gg$data[[2]]: data associated with geom_line as it is the 2nd geom
#c(1,2) & c(2,1): I have $group==3 ...
# ... so just need to flip 1st and 2nd datapoints within that group 

gg$data[[2]][gg$data[[2]]$group==3,][c(1,2),] <- 
gg$data[[2]][gg$data[[2]]$group==3,][c(2,1),]

gt <- ggplot_gtable(gg)

plot(gt)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem occurs due to `PositionDodgev`'s `compute_panel` function, which takes in a dataset sorted by x values, & returns a dataset sorted instead by y values (within each group) after making the necessary transformations to dodge positions vertically.

The following workaround defines a new ggproto object that inherits from `PositionDodgev`, but reorders the dataset in `compute_panel` before returning it:

```
# new ggproto based on PositionDodgev
PositionDodgeNew <- ggproto(
  "PositionDodgeNew", 
  PositionDodgev,
  compute_panel = function (data, params, scales){

    result <- ggstance:::collidev(data, params$height, 
                                  name = "position_dodgev", 
                                  strategy = ggstance:::pos_dodgev, 
                                  n = params$n, 
                                  check.height = FALSE)

    result <- result[order(result$group, result$x), ] # reordering by group & x

    result
  })

# position function that uses PositionDodgeNew instead of PositionDodgev
position_dodgenew <- function (height = NULL, preserve = c("total", "single")) {
  ggproto(NULL, PositionDodgeNew, height = height, preserve = match.arg(preserve))
}
```

Usage:

```
po <- position_dodgenew(height = 0.3)

ggplot(df,
       aes(x = x, y = y, col = group)) +
  geom_point(position = po) +
  geom_line(position = po)
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Thanks Z.Lin. Works great!